# How to rename files deleting the " character using the linux shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, batch-rename

I have a number of files with double quotes in the filename like this:

> "This_is_a_long_filename_with_quotes".mp3

I try to use the linux command rename, I can erase the underscore easily using

```
rename 's/_//g' *
```

but when I try with \" nothing happens (I use -n to see the changes):

```
rename -n 's/\"//g' *
```

nothing is renamed

thanks!

Comment: You say `ls | grep \"` returns nothing. How about `echo *\"*` or `ls *\"*`? If none of these commands show anything, you don't have files with double quotes in their names; you have files with *pairs of* single quotes in their names. Try `ls | grep \'`, `echo *\'*` or `ls *\'*`. If those commands find your files, rename them with `rename -n "s/'//g" *`.

Comment: Right they are not double quotes! see the comment below

Comment: They are "curly quotes". Try two `rename` operations while cutting and pasting the exact quote characters (open and close).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have "smart quotes" in your file names:

```
“Tokyo_String_Quartet-Beethoven_-Late_String_Quartets-CD1-11-Quartet”.mp3
```

Try the `rename` command with those inserted instead of `"`

Or without using `rename` you can do the `sed` option:

```
for f in *.mp3
    do
        new=$(echo $f | sed -E 's/[“”]//g')
        mv $f $new
    done
```

As with all batch shell operations using `mv` it is safest to test/run on a backup of the original folder... You can test by putting `echo` in place of `mv` when you first try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to escape escape double quote inside single guote.

```
rename -n 's/"//g' *
```

Comment: Anyway nothing is renamed with or without escape I don't know why

Comment: 1) On my debian rename is a soft link to another softlink in /etc/alternatives. Chase the links and use `dpkg -S ...` on the final file to find package providing the executable. 2) Use `dpkg -l package_name` to find package version --> on my system with `rename-0.20-3` the above command reported rewrites you wanted. 3) Which shell do you use? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: The problem is that they are not double quotes as suggested by @WildVelociraptor

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in Bash with this:

```
file=$(ls | grep \")
newName=$(echo $file | sed 's/\"//g')
mv $file $newName
```

Comment: Maybe the same problem here, because `ls | grep \"` returns nothing

Comment: Are you sure they're double quotes? It may help to copy and paste the filename elsewhere, to see how it's rendered. It might also be an issue with way the filename is encoded; ASCII vs Unicode, maybe?

Comment: Ohh they are not, this is the file name: “Tokyo_String_Quartet-Beethoven_-_Late_String_Quartets_-_CD1-11-Quartet,_Op._131_in_C_sharp_minor_-_Allegro”.mp3

Comment: You need to cut and paste the opening and closing double quotes and use **'s/[“”]//g'** in your rename. (PS I don't have this trouble with my Lindsay Quartet recordings!)

Comment: I have just seen that @beroe has made the same point under the original question, but I'll let my comment stand, as I have given the edit command you require.